# How to store and access large and frequently used data in XML?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jakarta-ee

I'm creating a forum website for my college project. Now just like the format of stackoverflow( ;) ), each question and answers will have comment facility. I'm expecting the size of questions and answers to be large and thus I don't want to use database like MYSQL. So what I'm planning to do is to create an XML file for each question within the 'question' tags and when some answers it append an 'answer' tag with it. Now can anyone help me on how to access the data from such XML files. I'm open to suggestions which tell me how to store the questions, and answers and the comments by some other way rather than with XML file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fear that storing individual XML files per question on disk will be much slower than using a relational database - consider IO and XML parsing overhead. Nevertheless, this is just a personal opinion without any evidence. I recommend to start with a simple solution and abstract the persistence layer away so that you can change your storage engine at a later time.

Comment: If you don't want to use MySQL, maybe go for SQLite? It stores everything in one local file...

Comment: A combination of mysql and files would be better, or perhaps a NoSql variant. Have you thought about how you are going to return a list of questions? Looks like premature optimisation this.

Comment: @home hey home so suppose a question is about 5000 characters in length then will it be advisable to store that question directly in the relational database like MySQL?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson hey so are you suggesting that I should create a seperate file for each question?

Comment: @SaumilSoni No but your problem will be implementing something like search or an equivalent to SO's tagging. If you don't need something like that, then maybe just files will work. Opening up every question file to see if it's about XML isn't going to be clever either. Designs are compromises.

Comment: Write all your requirements, then seek the best compromises to do a design, instead of designing something and then compromising your requirements...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yeah I agree so what if I store the data which would be around 5000 characters in length directly into the database? Will it impose any major drawback?

Comment: No different to storing words docs or images that in a relational db that. The preferred solution is to store the filename in the db and the content on the file system. If I was you I'd go for NoSqL, just using files will mean most of your time will be spent reinventing a relation db, instead of writing your app.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson thanks I'm looking forward on using NoSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would strongly suggest to use a relational database like MySQL**. If you are not talking about vast amounts of data, then relational databases are performing great. Since you deal with a college project, I suppose there will be no need to pay the overhead of moving to another solution.

Anyway, if you want to store your data in another non-relational format, **I would suggest moving to a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solution** and not using a simple file based solution. **I would also suggest using [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)** which has less overhead than XML. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is a NoSQL which is perfect at storing [JSON data](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/). Actually is is using [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) which is a binary JSON format.

Hope I helped!